# Properly closing Stream / StreamReader instance returned by function

Tags: c#, .net, stream, .net-2.0

I'm refactoring some code right now and found following function:

```
public static StreamReader DoWebRequest(string url, string method)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.Method = method;
    req.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
    HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    return new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
}
```

and later

```
string result = Helper.DoWebRequest(ServerUrl, "GET").ReadToEnd();
```

I've used streams a lot and always put `HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()` and also stream readers into using block. But how should I do that in this particular case? Is the above code ok or it's better to assign the StreamReader to the new variable and explicitely close it after the call of ReadToEnd(); (or inside of using block) like this:

```
using(StreamReader sr = Helper.DoWebRequest(ServerUrl, "GET"))
{
  string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: For the example shown, IMO the real answer is "use `WebClient` / `DownloadString` " - it does everything you do here, but in much less code, plus it will get the encoding right

Comment: @MarcGravell this example is just an example. The above DoWebRequest function is used to retrieve a streamReader as well, for example for our data provider jsDataProvider(TextReader reader). I would really love to know if string result = Helper.DoWebRequest(ServerUrl, "GET").ReadToEnd(); is a kind of memory leak (as I don't close the stream explicitely) or it's ok? Or maybe there are some other problems? thanks

Comment: There's no *inherent* issues, as long as the returned data isn't obscenely big. If it returns 1 gigabyte of text, expect pain from `ReadToEnd`

Comment: @MarcGravell a big amount of data is possible. But my question is more about the proper usage. Puting req.GetResponse() and Helper.DoWebRequest() into using blocks is always fine AFAIK. But what about string result = Helper.DoWebRequest(ServerUrl, "GET").ReadToEnd(); ? Will the stream be closed automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always write another function that does both:

```
public static String ReadToEndAndClose(this StreamReader stream)
{
    using(var sr = stream)
    {
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Needs to be `static` to work as an extension method (`this`) - but sure, that'll work